# Return Statement in Finding Max Even Number

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code to show the max even number in a list, but something isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
numbers = [1, 4, 15, 456, 3, 6]

def FindMaxEven(numbers):

    max_even = 0
    for x in numbers:
        if (x % 2)==0:
            if x > max_even:
                max_even = x
                return max_even
FindMaxEven(numbers)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I need to have a return statement to return the max_even, but I am not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: `return max_even` is indented too far. You return the first even number you see that's greater than zero. You need to get all the way through the loop before returning.

Comment: "I need to have a return statement to return the max_even". Right, so think carefully about *when* the value should be `return`ed. Remember, this only happens once per function call. What needs to have happened before you can know the value?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you do this

```
def FindMaxEven(numbers):
   return max([number for number in numbers if number % 2 == 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def FindMaxEven(numbers):

    max_even = 0
    for x in numbers:
        if (x % 2)==0:
            if x > max_even:
                max_even = x
    return max_even
```

The return statement is placed inside the for loop.
So it will return the first even number instead of returning the maximum value of the number

If it is placed outside the loop this will return the maximum value

Answer (score 1):

The return should be just below the for loop.

```
def FindMaxEven(numbers):

    max_even = 0
    for x in numbers:
        if (x % 2)==0:
            if x > max_even:
                max_even = x
    return max_even # <----------- Here
FindMaxEven(numbers)
```

**Alternate ways:**

```
max(i for i in numbers if i % 2==0)
```

Or

```
def FindMaxEven(numbers):
    max_even = 0
    for x in numbers:
        if (x % 2==0) and x > max_even:
            max_even = x
    return max_even
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning at the end of the loop, not inside the if statement, so remove the indentation before `return`.

```
max_even = 0
for x in numbers:
    if (x % 2)==0:
        if x > max_even:
            max_even = x
return max_even
```

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your code and commented the mistakes:

```
numbers = [1, 4, 15, 456, 3, 6]

def FindMaxEven(numbers):

    max_even = 0
    for x in numbers:
        if (x % 2)==0:
            if x > max_even:
                max_even = x

    return max_even     #return was indented way too much
res=FindMaxEven(numbers)    #the function returns a value and there was
                             #no variable created to store that value
print(res)
```

The `return max_even` statement was in the wrong code block thus it was not returning the correct value. It should be used in the `for loop` code block so that all the values of the list are checked before the return statement is run.

The `return` statement always returns a value that needs to be stored in a variable.

Hope this was helpful!